SwiftUI API Integration
I'm new to SwiftUI, and I have a question regarding API URLs. Currently, I'm hardcoding the API URL directly into my code, but I'm wondering if there's a better and safer way to store it.

Should I hardcode the API URL directly in my SwiftUI code?
Is there a best practice for securely storing API URLs so they are easy to access and reuse across my project?
I’d appreciate any suggestions or examples of how to manage this properly.

Thank you!

You talk about "SwiftUI" but I'm not sure you're fully aware of what you're talking. You should have a different class/struct to make the API calls, that one might handle the URLs, or it could also be on a different place, and the "SwiftUI" which is only for "UI" part call that class. It's all about separation of "roles".

I mean the swift in general the code that is for calling

In SwiftUI, to store your url string
you could try using @AppStorage("serverUrl") var urlString: String = "https://....."
see AppStorage
and also what is AppStorage. Note, to store any sensitive info (passwords etc...), use keychain.

You would use an API layer over the network service layer. It exposes functions like func fetchSomething(with: Parameter) async throws -> Something. As you see, the function is "domain specific", but there's no URL. The URL is used in yet another layer, below this one, the network layer. This one uses "HTTP terminology", i.e. it uses URLs, URLRequest, HTTPResponses, HTTP headers, etc., and it uses a configuration (in several variants  for production, test, staging). This config defines your base URL.  It can be hard-coded, or read from a file, or setup during delivery on the CI.


Store as Environment Variable
a. Go to Xcode -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme.
b. Under the Run tab, click Environment Variables.
c. Add your environment variable, for example: API_URL = https://your-api-  url.com/
d.Access the Variable anywhere in project
if let apiUrl = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["API_URL"] {
print(apiUrl)
}

You can also store in info.plist file , then you can use that.


NOTE -> From my opinion you can use these method to store only base url . And for end point make and singleton class for them . because in app we have base url 2-3(like Development, Staging, or Productio) but we have large number of end-point
